# (SQL) Pulling linked profiles from two tables using Knex

Tags: sql, join, knex.js

I currently have two tables with the following data:

```
Parent: ID, Name, PIN
Child: ID, Name, PIN, ParentID
```

I currently have my query set up like this with Knex:

```
db('Parents AS P')
    .join('Children AS C', 'C.ParentID', 'P.ID')
    .where('C.ParentID', ID)
    .select([
      'C.PIN AS ChildPIN',
      'C.Name AS ChildName',
      'P.Name AS ParentName',
      'P.PIN AS ParentPIN',
    ])
```

I'm currently parsing the data into the following format:

```
[
  { Name: 'Name1', PIN: '1234', type: 'Parent' },
  { Name: 'Name2', PIN: '2345', type: 'Child' }
]
```

This works totally fine except for the cases where the parent has no children, as it won't pull any data at all, including parent info. Is there any workaround in this case to avoid having to do a second API request? Thank you!

Comment: Do you want a SQL language answer, or a Knex answer?

Comment: Knex answer would be better, but even if you can only provide an SQL answer as a jumping-off point that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Left Outer Join instead of join

```
db('Parents AS P')
  .leftOuterJoin('Children AS C', 'C.ParentID', 'P.ID')
  .where('C.ParentID', ID)
  .select([
    'C.PIN AS ChildPIN',
    'C.Name AS ChildName',
    'P.Name AS ParentName',
    'P.PIN AS ParentPIN',
])
```

EDIT:

This was solved by using a left INNER join instead of outer! Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm... I tried this and it still returns an empty array when the parent has no children.

Comment: can you try  `.leftOuterJoin('C.ParentID', 'Children AS C', 'P.ID')` or fullOuterJoin

Comment: Hmm, that seems to throw an error. It seems likely that this just might not be possible in SQL? I've also tried switching the order of the join params with both full and left joins, no luck

Comment: I forgot to mention, I did end up solving it with an innerJoin(), thank you for the guidance!